# How do I graph two columns on the x axis with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using this code to make boxplots:

```
Fecundity <- read.csv('Fecundity.csv')

FecundityPlot <- ggplot(Fecundity, aes(x=Group, Sex, y=Fecundity)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill = fill, color = line) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Fecundity") +
  #scale_y_continuous(name = "Fecundity", breaks = seq(0, 80, 10), limits=c(0, 80)) +
  ggtitle("Fecundity") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 11)
```

My data looks like this:

```
ID              Group       Sex Generation  Fecundity   Strain
ORR-100-M-01    OR-R-100    M   1             0         ORR
ORR-100-M-02    OR-R-100    M   1             0         ORR
ORR-100-M-03    OR-R-100    M   1             0         ORR
JW-100-M-01     JW-100      M   1            13         JW
JW-100-M-02     JW-100      M   1             0         JW
JW-100-M-03     JW-100      M   1           114         JW
```

I would like to make a boxplot with ggplot2 that has a bar for each Group and Sex.  So there would be a box for Group=OR-R100 Sex=M next to OR-R100 F with Fecundity on the Y axis.

Additionally, how do I manually order the boxes so I have OR-R-20, OR-R-40, etc., in the desired order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Sex to any `aes()` (color, fill, alpha etc.) within `geom_boxplot()`  and ggplot will automatically split out females and males in each group and dodge the boxplots, and display a legend with sex.

```
FecundityPlot <- ggplot(Fecundity, aes(x=Group, Sex, y=Fecundity)) + 
                        geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sex))
```

Or, if you want all of your labels on the y axis, another approach would be to make a new column concatenating group and sex, then plot using that as the x variable

```
Fecundity$new.group <- paste(Fecundity$Group, Fecundity Sex)

FecundityPlot <- ggplot(Fecundity, aes(x=new.group, Sex, y=Fecundity)) + 
                        geom_boxplot()
```

To set a custom order for the groups, you need to make Group a factor and define the levels.  Defining the order of the levels in `factor()` will override the alphabetical default.

```
Fecundity$Group <- factor(Fecundity$Group, 
                          levels = c("OR-R-20", "OR-R-40", "JW-100"))
```

Comment: So this looks great, I like that they are interleaved by sex, but with geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sex)) how would I color each sex manually?  I can do it for a simpler boxplot that isn't interleaved like this, but can I specify a color for M and F?

Comment: If you don't like the default colors, `scale_fill_manual()` lets you specify colors.  I suggest you look at the [ggplot2 documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html) for details on this and other plot appearance customization

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (using `dplyr/tidyverse` pipes):

```
Fecundity %>%
 mutate(Group_sex = paste(Group, Sex)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = Group_sex, y = Fecundity)) +
 geom_boxplot()
```

Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `read.csv` call, or better yet, use the faster `read_csv` from `tidyverse`.

To set an order to the bars, you can use a `mutate(Group_sex = factor(Group_sex, levels = c( ... ))) %>%` line after the first mutate and provide an explicit order in `...` (if the number of different combinations is small).

Comment: I'm getting a Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()` or `aes_()`

Comment: Forgot the `aes` in `ggplot`. Added

Comment: Still getting it for some reason.  Direct copy

Comment: It's the `%>%` after the initial `ggplot()` call.  It should be a `+`

Comment: Thanks @JakeKaupp, fixed. Try now, user974887